# searching for microsoft sql server equivalent of postgresql form

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT nextval('AWARD_ID')
```

I am getting `nextval` as not built in function name in MS SQL Server. Kindly give any alternative if there is any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean something like IDENT_CURRENT():

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('FOO') + IDENT_INCR('FOO')
```

Comment: This calculates the next value but wouldn't advance the sequence (unlike Postgres' [`nextval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html))

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for [`SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR award_id`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx).